# Scrollify.js and jQuery scrollbar

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, vertical-scrolling, jquery-scrollify

I use [Scrollify.js](https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify) to animate scrolling between sections on my page.

Each section is set at the height of 100vh.

In the middle is a container that can be greater than the height of the section so I decided to use [jQuery scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) and I have a problem - if I use mouse scrollwheel sections jump, but the content is not scrolled.

How to deal with it?

Maybe detect the end of the scroll area and go to the next section? But how?
And what if the content will fit without scroll?

My code:

```
jsfiddle.net/1w60takz/2/
```

@edit:

On scrollify page is an example that suits me - 'Header and footer', 
but if there is more content than the height of the window - it does not work properly.

Maybe fix this will be easier?

Comment: Somebody help ?

Answer (score 0):

Set your middle container as a `standardScrollElement` in Scrollify

Answer (score 0):

Resolve this problem: https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify/issues/219

I wrote to the author of the script and introduced an amendment.